# show linux process [Python]

Tags: python

Guy how i can read all process work in my computer and print it

i want process read then print ?

Comment: Do you want to see all currently running processes using Python? I'm confused by your wording.

Answer (score 2):

one of the possible ways is to parse the output of some specialized system process "viewer" application

like:

```
import commands
cmd = 'ps ax'
for line in commands.getoutput(cmd).splitlines():
    # process the line
```

Comment: @strik3r i don't know this software.. make sure it does produce the data on the stdout..

Comment: works correctly in osx.   guess should work in most flavours of unix check if "ps ax" works in your shell